# Passing python function object into threading.Thread constructor when creating a new thread - Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, client-server

I am writing a TCP messaging application based on a client server model consisting of one server and multiple clients communicating concurrently. I know quite little about multi-threading and so in an effort to get a better understanding ofh ow to do this, I sourced some code online.

**OPS CODE:1/2**

```
def recv_handler():
    global t_lock
    global clients
    global serverSocket
    print('Server is up.')
    while True:
        # create a new connection for a new client
        connection_socket, client_address = serverSocket.accept()

        # create a new function handler for the client
        socket_handler = connection_handler(connection_socket, client_address)

        # create a new thread for the client socket
        socket_thread = threading.Thread(name=str(client_address), target=socket_handler)
        socket_thread.daemon = False
        socket_thread.start()
```

**OPS CODE:2/2**

```
# return a function as connection handler for a specific socket for multi threading
def connection_handler(connection_socket, client_address):
    def real_connection_handler():
        while True:
            data = connection_socket.recv(1024)
            ....
            more logic

    return real_connection_handler
```

Superficially, I think I understand what's happening here:

`recv_handler` is constantly listening for new client connections, and upon request creates a new dedicated socket for each new client connection.This happens by `connection_socket, client_address = serverSocket.accept()`.
Once a new new socket has been created, the socket and the address are passed to the
`connection_handler(connection_socket, client_address)` function, which returns the object `real_connection_handler()`.
Then a new thread is created with the real_connection_handler object as the target function in the thread constructor.

Why does OP do this? Specifically, why does OP set target to the inner function (real_connection_handler) instead of the outer function (connection_handler)? Why is he nesting functions here? Why not just do:

**MY CODE SUGGESTION 1/2**

```
def recv_handler():
    global t_lock
    global clients
    global serverSocket
    print('Server is up.')
    while True:
        # create a new connection for a new client
        connection_socket, client_address = serverSocket.accept()

        # create a new thread for the client socket
        socket_thread = threading.Thread(name=str(client_address),target=connection_handler(connection_socket, client_address))
        socket_thread.daemon = False
        socket_thread.start()
```

**MY CODE SUGGESTION 2/2**

```
def connection_handler(connection_socket, client_address):
        while True:
            data = connection_socket.recv(1024)
            ....
            more logic
```

Does my suggestion code invite competition over resources? Like forming a queue in accessing the connection_handler function? For example, if a very first client_connection_request_1 (call it conn_1) were to be established with the server and remain active in the connection_handler function while a second client_connection_request_2 (call it conn_2) were to be established, would conn_2 only gain access to the connection_handler function once conn_1 exited (i.e. stopped sending messages)?

This is my first ever post so I hope it's clear. I'm confused by what he's done and python is also new to me, so my question my in turn be confusing. I appreciate any clarity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "why does OP set target to the function object instead of the function itself" I really don't understand what you mean... The function object *is the function itself*

Comment: Yes you're right, that was poorly worded. But the question still remains, why does OP nest real_connection_handler() inside connection_handler()? Why not do what I suggested?